# pandas - How to upsample and select corresponding value for new cells

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with three clumns:
1. ID (int64): Object ID
2. DATETIME (datetime64[ns]): Date and time when the past four values of the Object were collected. Frequency can be less or more than one hour. Value of some 15mn intervals can be missing when two successive collection are separated by one hour and 15 min or more.
3. VALUES (string object): comma separated four values of the object. Each value is object's value during past 15 minutes interval. Example when collected values at 10AM are "0,1,2,3", this means that object's value was 0 between 9:45 and 10 AM, 1 between 9:30 and 9:45 AM etc...

I want to resample this dataframe with 15 minutes frequency and have for every 15 minutes interval the corresponding value without any explicit for loop (or with the minimum of loops) because it is a huge dataframe and looping will make execution too long...

Here's a sample of what I have for one single object:

```
ID,COLLECTION_DATETIME,VALUES
10000,2017-09-13 10:30:00,"2,1,0,3"
10000,2017-09-13 11:00:00,"6,5,2,1"
10000,2017-09-13 12:15:00,"0,0,0,2"
```

And here's the result I want to obtain:

```
ID,COLLECTION_DATETIME,VALUE
10000,2017-09-13 09:45:00,3
10000,2017-09-13 10:00:00,0
10000,2017-09-13 10:15:00,1
10000,2017-09-13 10:30:00,2
10000,2017-09-13 10:45:00,5
10000,2017-09-13 11:00:00,6
10000,2017-09-13 11:15:00,NaN
10000,2017-09-13 11:30:00,2
10000,2017-09-13 11:45:00,0
10000,2017-09-13 12:00:00,0
10000,2017-09-13 12:15:00,0
```

I guess this can be done by using 'COLLECTION_DATETIME' column as index and resample with 15min frequency, splitting 'VALUES' column (df['VALUES'].str.split(',',expand=True)) and transposing it, somehow affecting the result to a new column of df.resample('15min') and deleting duplicate intervals but I still can't do it
Any idea or indication would help.

Comment: Why `Nan` instead of 0? All of the  values are of size 4

Comment: Because object's value in this interval was not collected and may not be 0. Any other unused value (say 999) can be used in place of Nan.

Comment: 10000,2017-09-13 10:30:00,"2,1,0,3" means that this object had value 2 between 10:15 and 10:30 (so desired value for DATE_TIME 2017-09-13 10:30:00 in the Upsampled dataframe should be 2 (value of past single 15min interval)), 1 between 10:00 and 10:15, 0 between 09:45 and 10:00 and 3 between 09:30 and 09:45 (==> it is correct above)

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for checking but I don't see any mistake here. May be the confusion is because in the explanation  values are "0,1,2,3" and in the provided sample they are "2, 1, 0, x". Regarding overlapping ranges, as in the provided sample above, the goal is to delete duplicates (same value is present in all overlapping ranges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
#change order of values
df['VALUES'] = df['VALUES'].str[::-1]
#repeat index by len of splitted values
a = df['VALUES'].str.split(',')
l = a.str.len()
#flatten column VALUES
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(l)].assign(VALUES=np.concatenate(a))
#convert index to column and create unique index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
    index     ID COLLECTION_DATETIME VALUES
0       0  10000 2017-09-13 10:30:00      3
1       0  10000 2017-09-13 10:30:00      0
2       0  10000 2017-09-13 10:30:00      1
3       0  10000 2017-09-13 10:30:00      2
4       1  10000 2017-09-13 11:00:00      1
5       1  10000 2017-09-13 11:00:00      2
6       1  10000 2017-09-13 11:00:00      5
7       1  10000 2017-09-13 11:00:00      6
8       2  10000 2017-09-13 12:15:00      2
9       2  10000 2017-09-13 12:15:00      0
10      2  10000 2017-09-13 12:15:00      0
11      2  10000 2017-09-13 12:15:00      0
```

---

```
#subtract timedelta by count each datetime
a = pd.to_timedelta(df[::-1].groupby('index').cumcount() * 15, unit='T')
df['COLLECTION_DATETIME'] = df['COLLECTION_DATETIME'] - a
df = df.set_index('COLLECTION_DATETIME').drop('index', axis=1)
#create unique DatetimeIndex and convert frequency
df = df.groupby(level=0).first().asfreq('15min')
#replace NaN by forward filling
df['ID'] = df['ID'].ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
                        ID VALUES
COLLECTION_DATETIME              
2017-09-13 09:45:00  10000      3
2017-09-13 10:00:00  10000      0
2017-09-13 10:15:00  10000      1
2017-09-13 10:30:00  10000      2
2017-09-13 10:45:00  10000      5
2017-09-13 11:00:00  10000      6
2017-09-13 11:15:00  10000    NaN
2017-09-13 11:30:00  10000      2
2017-09-13 11:45:00  10000      0
2017-09-13 12:00:00  10000      0
2017-09-13 12:15:00  10000      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael

Comment: Finally this works well with one single ID in the dataframe (as in the example) but with many IDs this will not produce a correct result: the groupby(level=0).first() part will keep only the first ID. Is it possible to have the result for multiple IDs without looping on df['ID'].unique() and concat all results for all IDs?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because pandas does not support it :( Need always unique index.